# How to invoke web service in client which has CustomBinding endpoints?

Tags: wcf, custom-binding

I have WCF web service with custombinding as endpoint. I would like to invoke this web service (hosted on IIS) from my client application.

**The service contract looks as below:**

```
 [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/management/2012/01/enrollment")]
    [XmlSerializerFormat]
    public interface IDiscoveryService
    {    
        [OperationContract(Name = "Get")]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
        string DiscoveryGet();
    }
```

**The Web.COnfig file contents looks like:**

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="NewBinding0">
          <textMessageEncoding />
          <httpTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="DiscoveryWebService.DiscoveryService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0"
          contract="DiscoveryWebService.IDiscoveryService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**The client application codes looks like:**

```
 string uri = " http://localhost/EnrollmentServer/Discovery.svc";

 HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
 req.ContentType = "unknown";
 req.Method = "GET";
 WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();

 StreamReader loResponseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), false);

 string responseString = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
```

I am getting HTML content of WSDL file instead of the string returned by Get method. I am not getting whether I am doing it in the right way or not?

I would appreciate the help in this regard.

Comment: I have tried as per the below answer provided by "carlosfigueira". Looks like some wrong with that, with these changes even my web service is not working with WCF Test client too.

Answer (score 1):

The `[WebGet]` (and `[WebInvoke]`) attribute is only honored for an endpoint which uses the `webMessageEncoding` binding element; with a HTTP transport with the `manualAddressing` property set to `true`, and also the `<webHttp/>` endpoint behavior - which your service doesn't have. If you make the changes listed below, it should work:

**Service contract**:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/management/2012/01/enrollment")]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
public interface IDiscoveryService
{    
    [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    string DiscoveryGet();
}
```

**Web.config**:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="NewBinding0">
          <webMessageEncoding />
          <httpTransport manualAddressing="true" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="DiscoveryWebService.DiscoveryService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0"
          contract="DiscoveryWebService.IDiscoveryService" behaviorConfiguration="Web" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Client code**:

```
 string uri = "http://localhost/EnrollmentServer/Discovery.svc/DiscoveryGet";

 HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
 req.Method = "GET";
 WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();

 StreamReader loResponseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), false);

 string responseString = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: In that case, how can I use HTTP GET and POST to send and receive soap xml? Please can you respond to this query? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303466/wcf-how-to-choose-right-binding-and-service-contract-when-the-request-and-respo

Comment: When I read some of the blogs and it conveys that Soap 1.2 supports HTTP GET and POST. Can you suggest me how I achieve this using soap 1.2 services instead of web http binding?